# Dynamically Calling PHP Class Methods

Tags: php, security

Is there any security problem with dynamically calling a method in a class from user input. For example:

```
<?php
    class A {
        public function foo() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $obj = new A();

    $method = $_GET['method'];

    $obj->$method();
```

I am aware that the user will be able to call any method within `A`, and I am fine with that. I am just curious if there may be other possible security issues.

Comment: If you have problematic methods, just don't make them public. Apart from that I can't think of any problem. Be careful with inheritances and inherited methods by the same reasons.

Comment: You might want to vet the methods that it's permitted to call (via a whitelist)... not just to test for public methods (trying to call a private method would error), but to prevent users hacking to call __destruct

Comment: It also gets fun if the methods require arguments, you certainly need to do some form of vetting if these are user-supplied as well

Comment: It is for an api, there are checks to make sure the correct parameters are given and the method exists. Looking for the gotchas, like a user calling  `__destruct`.

Comment: @mitmaro - trap for every magic method, otherwise __get or __call could also be abused easily

Comment: it's one of the few cases where a try/catch is good practice.

Comment: I will disallow methods starting with `_`, should solve that problem. Also you should have posted an answer. :)

Comment: @MitMaro - Pascal MARTIN needs the rep more than me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your user will be able to try calling any possible method from your class -- even try to call non-existant methods *(and get a Fatal Error)*.

If you're fine with this... well, I suppose this is OK.

It doesn't look nice, but I don't think one could inject any other kind of code.

Still, I would at least check if the method exists -- using [**`method_exists()`**][1]

Comment: `method_exists` will definitely be used along with a few other checks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its probably a bad idea, maybe you should restrict allowed methods. Maybe define allowed methods in an array then throw an exception if $method is not in this whitelist.

Also you will need to use the magic __call($name, $args) method to allow these user defined methods to be called.